# VideoJS Advanced Styling in Safari

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm using the [VideoJS Advanced](http://videojs.com/advanced/) example. In Chrome, the playlist wraps underneath the video at a certain breakpoint:

[image]

In Safari, the playlist remains on the right of the video, and you have to scroll within the browser to see the playlist:

[image]

I need the Safari playlist to wrap, due to a requirement of horizontally placing the playlist videos on wrap.

I really don't want to have to add a Safari conditional to my CSS. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should post some example HTML or CSS but check your playlist floats and width at that breakpoint.  They should be 100% and a float:left.

Also tags that aren't closed can cause this, so validate your HTML.